# Django advanced form validation how-to?

Tags: django, validation

From looking over the documentation, it seems that the form clean() method is only intended to do lightweight syntax-related validation, such as checking that an email address ends in ".com" or ".edu", or ensuring that the user selects no more than three items from a "pick your top three favorite TV shows" list.

I'm working on an application that allows users to set their password and I want to make sure that their password doesn't contain their login or their real name, and the clean() method doesn't seem like the right place to do this kind of checking, both from a design standpoint and also from the practical limitation that the clean() method doesn't have access to the session data.

Where is the best place to do more heavyweight validation?  If I do some custom checking in the view after calling `form.is_valid()`, is there a way to get back to the standard form error handling?

I have an idea the code might look like this:

```
def process_login(request):
    """Display or process the login form."""

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            if password_is_bad(password, request):
                # what now?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're field-specific validation hooks too: `clean_$fieldname`.  See details in [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/) of django docs.

Update: As for passing session info to form, this is easily done via attribute assignment:

```
form = LoginForm(request.POST)
form.session = request.session
```

then you can access `self.session` in `clean_password` method.

Comment: But clean_password() doesn't have access to the session data, does it?  I need access to the session data so I can determine the user's identity and look up their login name and real name.

Comment: Updated my answer with solution to session access

Comment: +1: This is a tiny bit better than using the `__init__` for the Form object.

Comment: Allow me to advocate for `__init__` a bit more: it makes the API of the form more obvious. Using the technique proposed in this answer, a user of `LoginForm` doesn't realize he needs to set the session attribute until `clean()` gets called and he decodes a deep traceback. Using `__init__` makes it clear what objects the form requires, and a programming error will be detected at construction time rather than at validation time.

Comment: I'd personally use `__init__` overriding when the same form is used in 3+ different places.  Before that, quick and dirtly solution is just simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to do all validation in the form. If I'm thinking in terms of object responsibilities, I think of the form as the object that describes the components of the form and how to convert between an HTML form and a *valid* python object, where "valid" includes application-specific requirements.

If a form needs information that it doesn't normally have access to I pass that information to the form's constructor. Untested code follows:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, session, *args, **kwargs):
        self.session = session
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        # does something with self.session
```

The advantage of this approach is that your views can frequently be made very generic, often to the point of merely passing an instantiated form object to a custom generic view.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to validate some parts of the form in the view, then you can raise a ValidationError exception, which would take the user back and display your error message.

```
from django.forms.util import ValidationError

if len( form.cleaned_data['password'] ) < 5:
    raise ValidationError('You have to type at least five characters')
```

Comment: If you raise an exception in the view won't that cause the server to respond with a 500 error?

Comment: Indeed it will.  I was hoping for some way to flow back into the standard form error handling that occurs within clean().  Raising a ValidationError in the view just causes a server 500 error.

Comment: I was quite sure, that if you use it with the form object, it will not "raise" the http 500 error.

Comment: raise form.ValidationError gets you this error: 'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'ValidationError'

Comment: Unfurtunately that's correct, I'm sorry for the misleading. I have found, possibly, the correct answer to that: [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#described-later)

Comment: definitely it will raise an error [AttributeError] but not a ValidationError